# How do I connect with spark to mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark, bigdata

When i try to load the data i get this message

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o172.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource. Please find packages at https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html I am working on jupyternotebook

The error happens at DefauldSource and it has some problem with package but i think i installed alle the packages

this is where i load

```
 df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load() 
 #df <- hier beginns my trouble idk why
```

I installed the pyspark and pymongo

#!pip install pyspark  pymongo

Requirement already satisfied: pyspark in /usr/local/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/python (3.3.2) Requirement already satisfied: py4j==0.10.9.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pyspark) (0.10.9.5) Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.3.3) Requirement already satisfied: dnspython<3.0.0,>=1.16.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pymongo) (2.3.0)

This is my code. I am trying to select the col "AGE", "W", "L", "DD2", "TD3", "PLUS_MINUS".

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

 spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MongoDB Spark Connector Example") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb:xxxx:<PORT>/<DB>.<COLLECTION>") \
    .getOrCreate()

 season_year = "1996"
 team_abbreviation = "CHH"

 df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load() 
 #df <- hier beginns my trouble idk why

 filtered_df = df.filter((col("season") == season_year) & (col("TEAM_ABBREVIATION") ==   team_abbreviation))

 selected_columns = ["AGE", "W", "L", "DD2", "TD3", "PLUS_MINUS"]
 selected_df = filtered_df.select(*selected_columns)


 selected_df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand, you may be missing the package `mongo-spark-connector`, so first of all try to install it like this:

```
!pip install --upgrade pymongo[srv],pyspark,pyarrow
```

and also make sure that you have added the `mongo-spark-connector` jar to your Spark `classpath`, and then add this to your Spark session configuration, and replace `3.0.1` with the version of the connector that you have installed:

```
.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1")
```

**Update**
so try to downgrading the `mongo-spark-connector` version to a lower version and see if it works?you can also try to specify the package version explicitly in the code like this (change `xxxx:/.` with your `MongoDB` connection string):

```
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
    .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb:xxxx:<PORT>/<DB>.<COLLECTION>") \
    .load()
```

and are you sure, you have added the connector jar file to the classpath correctly? please check it like this

```
echo $SPARK_CLASSPATH
```

good luck !